# Correctly rendering marker color and text using Markermanager

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3, markermanager

I am trying to display a list of map markers using MarkerManager. I'm passing in an array of StyledMarkers have ascending number for the text and a variety of colors. When the markers display, they all show the same number and color. It is always the color and number of the last item added to the list.

A Note: This code is on a web page that a built a couple of years ago, and it worked fine then. Have there been changes to to the Google Maps API that would obsolete the version of MarkerManager that I am running. I did a Google search and did not turn up anything to that effect.

Comment: Try version 3.9; there were changes in v3.10 that broke both the MarkerManager and StyledMarker.  Fixed version of both utility libraries were released I believe.

Comment: Going back to 3.9 fixed the problem. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

There were changes in v3.10 that broke both the MarkerManager and StyledMarker. Fixed version of both utility libraries were released I believe.

Look through the [issues list](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues) star any issues that apply to you; some have been addressed in updates to the utility library.  If there are any that don't have existing issue, create one.

This needs to be fixed before v3.9 is retired.